# How to use setter programmatically in universal windows app c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Please help me to use setter in c#.
Something like this:

```
Setter set = new Setter();
set.Target = image.Width;
```

Comment: For best practice Setter should be placed in xaml. Assign setter values for your custom controls.

Comment: I have no control in xaml view that i could assign setter to. i added controls in c# and i wand use setter in c# too.

Comment: Creating controls "programatically" in C# code is considered bad practice in XAML-based technologies. Whatever you're doing, delete all your code and do it the right way, using XAML and databinding.

Comment: @HighCore, thanks. i'm going to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to implement setters for image.width

```
 Setter setter1 = new Setter
           {
               Property = Image.WidthProperty,
               Value = 123,
           };
```

or/and

```
var setter2 = new Setter(Image.WidthProperty, 123);
```

edit: I was handwriting sorry

Comment: I'm sorry. i should be more clear. see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn765018.aspx#step_5__adapt_the_ui_to_different_window_sizes). i like to use those xaml codes in c#. thanks

Comment: @WithoutBrain1994 oh your mean Setter from style Setters?

Comment: I get this error "Cannot implicitly type 'double' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty'" for Property and this error "'Binding' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" for Value

Comment: @WithoutBrain1994 sorry i was handwritting, answere edited again

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. but that's ok. it seems that i have to learn data binding and i'm gonna.